# How do I rename xmlns="" with WriteStartElement?

Tags: c#, xml-namespaces, xna-4.0, xmlwriter

I'm attempting to make an XML that's going to be parsed by an XNA content reader. I'm using XMLWriter, and the format is supposed to be:

```
<XNAContent>
     <Assest Type="namespace">
          <Element>"Value"</Element>
     </Asset>
<XNAContent>
```

But when I use WriteStartElement to declare a namespace, I get:

```
 <XNAContent>
     <Assest xmlns="namespace">
          <Element>"Value"</Element>
     </Asset>
<XNAContent>
```

It's important that I have `Asset Type=` instead of `Asset xmlns=` because of what the pipeline expects, but I can't find an overload that let's me rename that default tag.

Is there a way for XMLWriter to let me put my own tag there as described?  Thanks, all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing XML attributes with namespaces, `xmlns` is a 'special' attribute that defines the namespace for an XML element and its children. Whereas your `Type` is simple an attribute. To write an attribute value use the [WriteAttributeString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z46xs1.aspx) method.

For example:

```
 writer.WriteStartElement("Asset");

 writer.WriteAttributeString("Type", "namespace");

 writer.WriteEndElement();
```

will result in

```
<Asset Type="namespace">
</Asset>
```